# How to avoid manual entry of login and password everytime Access connects to SQL Server without using Windows Authentication

Tags: ms-access, connection, azure-sql-database, windows-authentication, dsn

I am connecting to an Azure Server to import data hosted by a 3rd party.  I can not use Windows Authentication to connect due to security protocols between their company and mine.  I have to use server-side authentication with a username and password.  I am connecting to Azure using OBDC through DSN.  The problem is each time I open Access and connect to the Azure tables, I get a connection error that I have to correct by manually unchecking "Use Trusted Connection" then entering that server's username and password.  Is there a way to automate that process?

Comment: When you created the DSN did you choose SQL Server authentication instead of Windows Authentication? If you are using Microsoft Access you can create a linked table to Azure SQL Database tables using that DSN.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can use to fix this issue.

One way, is to delete all your table links, and then re-link. Just make sure you check the box to save the uid/password when you do this. As a result, Access will remember the settings for the lined tables. However, if you “often” or “always” need to prompt the user for uid/logon, then you have to re-link the tables each time. However, if you not needing to re-link or change the uid/password, then this is a simple and fine solution.

Just keep in mind that your uid/password is in “plain” sight the linked tables – so only you can decide if this is a “non issue”, or something that you want to prevent users from seeing.

The other approach is to “leave” your lined tables as they are, and execute a logon in your startup code. Once you executed a logon, then your existing linked tables (without the uid/password saved) will now work.

You can use the following code to “log on” to the server, and once done, then all of those prompts should not appear.

```
Function TestLogin(strCon As String) As Boolean

  On Error GoTo TestError

  Dim dbs          As DAO.Database
  Dim qdf          As DAO.QueryDef

  Set dbs = CurrentDb()
  Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("")

   qdf.connect = strCon

   qdf.ReturnsRecords = False

   'Any VALID SQL statement that runs on server will work below.
   ' this does assume user has enough rights to query built in
   ' system tables

   qdf.sql = "SELECT 1 "
   qdf.Execute

   TestLogin = True

   Exit Function

TestError:
   TestLogin = False
   Exit Function

End Function
```

You have to pass the above a correctly formatted connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I will try the "log on" technique and let you know how it goes.   To give a little more background,  I am linked into several backend databases.   The ones on on the companyserver auto login using Windows Authentication.   The tables on a third party developer's server can not be linked with Windos Authentication due to security issues that poses.   The third party connections have to use the developer's login and password.